# How can I do dynamic link with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Consider the main category subcategory mentality. I want to have the following when a link is clicked.

I can do : www.localhost.com/category/

i want to do: www.localhost.com/category/vehicle

derivatives: www.localhost.com/category/vehicle/bmw
              www.localhost.com/category/vehicle/bmw/bmm-x7-series

```
Route::get('/category/{id}', 'CategoryController@index')->name('category.index');
          `
```

---

my route below:

```
Route::get('/category/{slug}', 'CategoryController@index')->where('slug' , '[\w\d\-\_]+');
```

I created a control named CategoryController

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
  public function index($slug)
  {
    $category = Category::where('slug' , $slug)->first();
    return view('category.show' , compact('category'));
  }
```

my view content(category.show.blade.php)

```
{{$category->slug}}
          <a href="{{ url('/category/' . $category->slug) }}" class="uhover">life is good. {{url($category->slug)}}</a>
```

Comment: first glance, I think your issue is that you are using the `{id}` token, which IIRC laravel thinks should be an integer, so maybe try using a different variable name. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003097/dynamic-routing-in-laravel-5-application) may provide some context for your conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the category / brand of the vehicles in the URL and not the ID, then you will need to remove `/{id}` from your route and replace it with a `/{slug}`.

So you route would probably look like this:

```
Route::get('/category/{slug}', 'CategoryController@index')->name('category.index');
```

You will have to change your method to something like:

```
// Show Method
public function show($slug){
    $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    return view('game.show', compact('category'));
}
```

Ideally, to make sure that the slug is unique, you would store it in the database. You can take advantage of Laravel's [slug helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-slug) to do so and if the slug already exists, just append a suffix to make it unique.

You can use generate the slug model:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function ($model) {
            $model->slug = str_slug($model->name);
        });
    }
}
```

If you want to use route–model binding, then you’ll need to tell Eloquent the column to use should be your `slug` column instead

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but do not apply. :(

Comment: how come? Did I misunderstand your question? Give us more details so we can help.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not really know English. Thank you for your interest.